# Reading Object in List; cannot be cast

Tags: java, list, casting

I think I have a simple mistake in my code but I can't find it.

I have a list of Objects (type of an entity) and I want to read the content of the objects in the list.

In my opinion something like:

```
object.get(1).getTitle();

List<HtMeldungen> meldungen = q.getResultList();

List<MeldungsBean> meldungsliste = new ArrayList();
MeldungsBean mb = null;
HtMeldungen tempMeldungen = null;

int i = 0;
int k = meldungen.size() - 1;

for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    mb = new MeldungsBean();
    tempMeldungen = (HtMeldungen) meldungen.get(i);

    mb.setTitel(tempMeldungen.getTitle());
    mb.setAutor(tempMeldungen.getAutor());
    mb.setMeldungstext(tempMeldungen.getText());

    meldungsliste.add(mb);
}
```

My list named `meldungen` is filled with objects of type HtMeldungen.

I get the error:

```
DBEntities.classic.HtMeldungen cannot be cast to DBEntities.classic.HtMeldungen
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what kind of objects do you have in this list? Are they HtMeldungen or some extension of it? BTW you should use an iterator to traverse the list.

Comment: Is HtMeldungen a sub class of MeldungsBean?

Comment: is it a runtime exception or compile-time?

Comment: Declare your list like this:
`List<MeldungsBean> meldungsliste = new ArrayList<MeldungsBean>();`

Comment: Is it failing on q.getResultList() or (HtMeldungen) meldungen.get(i)? Can you print a piece of the stack trace?

Comment: Note: the convention is to use English names for classes, methods, variables etc., even if English is not your native tongue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `q.getResultList()` gets a list with instances of `HtMeldungen`?
If not, then the line

```
List<HtMeldungen> meldungen = q.getResultList();
```

is - depending of your compiler switches - syntactically correct, but the list can contain instances of a different class, and later in the line

```
tempMeldungen = (HtMeldungen) meldungen.get(i);
```

you get your exception, because that what the compiler thinks it must be instance of `HtMeldungen` in fact isn't.
Try the code

```
if (meldungen.get(i) instanceof HtMeldungen) {
  tempMeldungen = (HtMeldungen) meldungen.get(i);
} else {
  throw new RuntimeException("Got instance of class " + meldungen.get(i).getClass());
}
```

then you get an understandable error if your assumption should have been wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll get the error: DBEntities.classic.HtMeldungen cannot be cast to DBEntities.classic.HtMeldungen

Since the error message indicates that an object of HtMeldungen cannot be cast to HtMeldungen (which seems contradictory), I would think that you might have this class loading twice in your build.  Please check to see if your build path is putting the same jar in the build twice.  That is what usually causes this error.